# Nokia Qt Mobility: How to get Photos from memory card?

Tags: qt, qt-mobility

I am making photo gallery application in Nokia Qt, I want to show pictures from device's memory card. How can i get pictures from memory card in Qt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an addendum to eburger's answer, QtMobility's QSystemStorageInfo can be used to determine which (or if) one of the drives is the memory card drive:

```
QSystemStorageInfo systemInfo;
QStringList driveList = systemInfo.logicalDrives();
QString memPath = "";
for (int index = 0; index < driveList.count(); index++)
{
    if (QSystemStorageInfo::RemovableDrive == systemInfo.typeForDrive(driveList[index]))

    {
        memPath = driveList[index];
        break; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

DocumentGallery in QtMobility should do the job: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility-1.1.0/gallery.html. Use filters to filter out files, that dont have the memory card drive letter.